# Literature on chess engines' playing style

Tags: engines, style

I'm aware of Matthew Sadler and Jozarov's outputs, do you have any other suggestions?

Any first-hand attempt of trying to describe engines' playing main themes would also be welcome.

Comment: Do you have a link to this: "Matthew Sadler and Jozarov's outputs"

Comment: Both of them have their respective youtube channels, ([Sadler](https://www.youtube.com/@SiliconRoadChess), [, Jozarov](https://www.youtube.com/@Jozarovschesschannel)). 
Sadler has also published a couple of books on the coupling of chess and AI ([link](https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/190536.Matthew_Sadler)). I have the Silicon Road to Chess Improvement and really liking it, although it's too focused in 1.D4 for my likings.
Personally I really like Sadler's resources, since he is not only an incredibly strong GM but he's also dedicated A LOT of attention to computer chess.